# How can i hide default navigation bar tin color

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

i was trying to create custom navigation bar. here is my code

```
let color = UIColor(hex: "BC324A")
 let navigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width,height: 50))
            navigationBar.barTintColor = color
            navigationBar.backgroundColor = color


    let button = UIButton.init(type: .custom)
        button.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "MenuI.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(BaseViewController.onSlideMenuButtonPressed(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        button.frame = CGRect.init(x: 50, y: 0, width: 20, height: 30)
            button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            button.layer.borderWidth = 1
            button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        let customBarItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)



    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [customBarItem]

            navigationBar.items = [navigationItem]

        // Make the navigation bar a subview of the current view controller
        self.view.addSubview(navigationBar)
```

here i an image of my navigation bar [image]

> if look this navigation closely you can see there is other color in my
>   custom navigation bar. How can i remove this color??

Comment: What other colour are you referring to? Is it the darker shade of red, or the grey border?

Comment: i am not talking about the boarder .. if you look closely than you can see a light red color is in front of  background red color

Comment: @FaizulKarim what is the exact issue? would you edit the question explain more details label? which color you mean here other color?. you should mention that color

Comment: The main issue is i just put a background color of my custom navigation bar.But if i put navigation bar tine color clear than than upper color change to black. but in default i make a lite white color infront of my custom navigation background color